# how to automatically backup docker Containers

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm running a gitlab instance in a docker container. What could be a good and smart solution to automatically make backups of this docker container?

Or is it a better way to make backups of the gitlab data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should backup data - the definition of the container (i.e. the image) should presumably already be source controlled?

Comment: Backing up gitlab data would be enough since the container can be destroyed and every modification would be lost, so as long as you have the sources and the data, you already have everything.

Comment: and what would be a good way to safe the gitlab data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the backup of your data and it is not required to backup the Docker instance. You can bring Docker instance from the Docker image at any time. But if you did some changes in the running Docker instance, then I would recommend you to create a new image from the running Docker instance using 'docker commit' command.  We can always run 'docker commit' on the running docker instance without stopping the Docker instance.

Comment: I think `docker commit` is bad practise, because you cannot see what changed. Better modify the *Dockerfile* and rebuild the image from there.

Comment: why is docker commit a bad practise? can a docker commit be stored on a different machine?

Comment: Because it's hard to see what's "inside" your image after a couple of changes. If you have a Dockerfile, you can clearly see how your image works. This will be a problem if you maintain your image with others or even share your image. But It's also hard for yourself if you ask yourself after 2 years "what have I done to receive the current state of my image?" In a Dockerfile it's clearly documentated.

Comment: And consider this: Lets say you use gitlab version 10.2.3. Later you want to switch to version 10.3.0. This will be a lot of effort compared to just edit one line in your Dockerfile (change `FROM gitlab:10.2.3` to `FROM gitlab:10.3.0`)

Comment: ...and not to forget about the size! Let's say you have some dependencies installed in your first image, but later you don't need them anymore: your image won't get smaller if you do a docker commit (because of Dockers Layer system, your image still includes your unused dependencies). Instead, rebuilding the image with a modified Dockerfile, you really get rid of unused stuff.

Comment: As pointed out by @Munchkin It is better to change the Dockerfile if you are the owner of the Docker but if you are using Docker from Dockerhub then you can use Docker commit.  You can use 'docker save' command to save the docker image you made out of docker commit and then you can use it on different machines.

Comment: @Viswesn You *always* use an image from Dockerhub (except you are building from scratch). So I recommend to always write your own Dockerfile if there is something you want to modify (starting with e.g. `FROM gitlab`...)